# What is the best way to send both Image and JSON to my express server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Ok, so I got a mongodb database, and I am using mongoose.

I have the following model for my product.

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true},
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: true },
  
  usage: { type: String, required: true },
  species: [{
    specie: { type: String, required: true }
  }],
  ingredients: [{
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    quantity: { type: String, required: true },
  }],
});
```

What I am trying to do is send both an image and JSON in a SINGULAR http request. I found out that this is not really possible. So what is the best to achieve this?
Send two different HTTP requests, one with the json/text data, and one with the file? This would mean that I need to edit my model and make the fields unrequired, and it would be a bit rough to debug in case something goes wrong with one of the requests.

```
  const newProduct = {
        name: name,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        usage: usage,
        ingredients: itemList,
        species: speciesList,
        image: image,
      };


     const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([
    { name: "", quantity: "" },
  ]);
  const [speciesList, setSpeciesList] = useState([
    { specie: "" },
  ]);
```

This is what I am trying to send

Comment: I don't understand, why it shouldn't be able send JSON and image as String in one request. Can you pls explain a bit more?

Comment: I set my form header's content typ to multiform/data and it doesn't send the JSON properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. you can send the data to the express server with `multipart/form-data` structure and then in the server should parse received data and map the values as defined model and finally store into mongo db.